# The correct way to do raycasting on a mesh with a displacement map

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm relatively new to Three JS, and currently I've got a working demo of loading a displacement map on a plane, effectively creating a terrain. What I'd like to be able to do is find the intersecting coordinates of a ray and this terrain.

Currently, for the demo, I have it marking the object as red when moused over, however the terrain seems to be behaving as though it has no displacement map when the intersect check is performed.

How do I find the intersection of the plane, after the displacement has affected the mesh?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved this, and if so, how?